# Mongodb aggregate unwind

Tags: mongodb

Написать запрос-агрегацию для выборки всех студентов, у которых результат по экзамену (type: "exam") более 90% (использование unwind)

Пример одного студента:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "Aurelia Menendez",
    "scores": [{
        "type": "exam",
        "score": 60.06045071030959
    }, {
        "type": "quiz",
        "score": 52.79790691903873
    }, {
        "type": "homework",
        "score": 71.76133439165544
    }, {
        "type": "homework",
        "score": 34.85718117893772
    }]
}
```

Мой вариант:

```
db.students.aggregate([{$match: {$and: [{type:"exam"}, {score: {$gt: 90}}]}}, {$unwind: "$scores"}])
```

Подскажите плз, что не так

Answer (score 0):

type и score - вложенные документы, на втором уровне (они в массиве scores), а ты ищешь на первом уровне
подходящий вариант запроса для них см. здесь docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/